# jQuery Autocomplete not working with Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, oracle, spring-mvc

Here is my jsp snippet

```
<form:form>    
<form:input path = "state"  id = "state"/>
</form:form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#state").autocomplete({         
        source: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/getStatelist.htm'    
        }); 
});
</script>
```

Here is the controllers code which is supposed to return state list

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getStatelist.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getStateList(@RequestParam("term") String query) {

          ApplicationContext context = 
                     new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

          MasterJDBCTemplate dao = 
                  (MasterJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("masterJDBCTemplate");
           System.out.println(query);
           System.out.println("Controller called");

           List<String> fans = dao.getStateList(query);

           return fans;
    }
```

After running the code and typing into the textfield state , the controller is called and i get the correct results printed on console. A sample run is shown below.

```
g
Controller called
select state_desc from mst_state where state_desc like 'G%'
[GUJRAT, GOA]
gu
Controller called
select state_desc from mst_state where state_desc like 'GU%'
[GUJRAT]
guj
Controller called
select state_desc from mst_state where state_desc like 'GUJ%'
[GUJRAT]
```

However i am unable to see anything on front end. What am i missing ? What could be the reason  ??

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery UI documentation, the returned data from the REST service should be JSON.

Refer: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

To accommodate that, instead of specifying Accept Header attribute from **" * / * "** (i.e. **headers="Accept= * / *"**) specify **" application/json "** (i.e. **headers="Accept=application/json"**)